# Sync a Merging in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, merge

I was able to merge video and audio but the video is one frame off to the right. I'm trying every way I can see online but there's no way to sync that jump frame. I'm using the following code but I don't know if it's correct:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 0.04 -i "VIDEO.mp4" -i "SONIDO.wav"^ -c copy "SINC.mov"
```

Answer (score 0):

add/subtract `1 / [framerate]` to the offset to adjust by one frame

so a fps of 29.97 would give either of these commands:

`ffmpeg -itsoffset 0.0733667000333667 -i "VIDEO.mp4" -i "SONIDO.wav"^ -c copy "SINC.mov"`

`ffmpeg -itsoffset 0.0066332999666332965 -i "VIDEO.mp4" -i "SONIDO.wav"^ -c copy "SINC.mov"`

I am not sure how many decimal places are supported, but there comes a point that doesn't matter.